# Ошибка при добавлении новости. ValueError: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

Идея в том, что при добавлении новости, пользователю на почту приходит сообщение с новостью. По итогу на странице не грузятся поля формы, лишь кнопка "добавить новость". По клику на которую приходит последняя добавленная новость, а новая не добавляется. И выдает эту ошибку.

```
Views.py:
class PostCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'add.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    permission_required = ('news.add_post',)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'add.html')

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-post_data')[0]
        send_mail(
            subject=posts.heading,
            message=posts.content,
            from_email='***@yandex.ru',
            recipient_list=['***@gmail.com']
        )
```

Если убрать метод гет, то поля грузятся, но ошибка все та же. Если убрать методы гет, пост и сендмейл, то новость нормально добавляется.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `post` должен вернуть `HttpResponse`. Будьте внимательны

Можете использовать `redirect()`, `render()` или что то еще что вернет указанный выше объект. Выбирайте исходя из своих потребностей

Comment: К сожалению не помогает. Поля формы так же не появляются. return HttpResponse выдает другую ошибку.

Comment: Sample18, какую ошибку?